# JS/React - Live Search Bar With Mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After two days of being stuck on this component, I'm asking for any sort of help. I'm trying to search an API based on user input, and then filter that down to a more specific option as the user keeps typing. After solving a dozen or so errors, I'm still left with "Can't find variable 'Query'", and I just can't seem to find or figure out what exactly it's wanting. There was another post on here that led me in the right direction, but didn't provide any sort of answer for the issue I'm having. Any help here would be appreciated.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import axiosRateLimit from "axios-rate-limit";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SearchBar from "react-native-elements/dist/searchbar/SearchBar-ios";

class CardSearch extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    filteredData: [],
    query: "",
  };

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const query = event.target.value;

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const filteredData = prevState.data.filter((element) => {
        return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
      });
      return {
        query,
        filteredData,
      };
    });
  };

  getData = () => {
    axiosRateLimit(
      axios.get(`https://api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete?q=${query}`),
      { maxRPS: 8 }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const filteredData = data.filter((element) => {
          return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });
        this.setState({
          data,
          filteredData,
        });
      });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder='Search For...'
          value={this.state.query}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <div>
          {this.state.filteredData.map((i) => (
            <p>{i.name}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default CardSearch;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: where exactly you are facing error? and I think `onChangeText` will return value not an event. https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/searchbar/

Comment: I updated the original post with a picture of the error I'm getting.

Comment: Please post ***text*** and not images of text.

Comment: To access state variable you need to use `this.state` so try with `this.state.query` instead of trying to access query state directly.

Comment: Apologies - I added the text snippet of the code as well.

I assume you mean using this.state.query in the API link? Doing so gives me the following:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'axios.interceptors.request')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this Link. You are not setting the State in a Constructor. And as already mentioned in the comments you will then have to access the query using `this.state.query`

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

The Code-Sample from the React Documentation:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add the content that you are mentioning from the link here as a quote in case the the docs go down or change.

Comment: Thanks for the Pointer. I added the correct code snippet.